# How do you save a file from NTLM authenticated URL in Perl Script

Tags: perl, download, ntlm

I'm really new to Perl Script and I'm developing a script to access a URL with NTLM authentication and save the response content in a folder. This content is a .xls, .doc, .pdf, .ppt, etc file. Actually,I was able to develop the NTLM authentication code. But my other requirement is to save the response content to a folder in the server. Can you help me with this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use LWP::UserAgent;  
use HTTP::Request::Common;  

my $url = "http://myurl.com/AdsSDAF34141J";
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(keep_alive => 1);  

my $username = 'ap\<username>';
my $password = '<password>';

$ua->credentials('myurl.com:80', '', $username, $password);  
my $req = GET $url;   
print "--Peforming request now...---------\n";  
my $res = $ua->request($req);  
print "--Done with request ...---------\n";  


if ($res->is_success) {  
    print $res->content;  
} else {  
    print "Error: " . $res->status_line . "\n";  
}  

exit 0;
```

I want to save the $res->content into a folder. Like I said this $res->content is a file of type .xls, .doc, .ppt, etc. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should show some code and where your problem is.

Comment: I already updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like this way:

```
if ($res->is_success) {  
  my $filename = 'file.xls';
  open(my $fh,'>',$filename) or die $!;
  binmode($fh);
  print $fh $res->content; 
  close($fh);
} else {
```

or

```
### this way it automatically stored in that file
my $filename = 'file.xls';
$ua->request( $req, $filename );
```